# VBA VeryHidden multiple tabs

Tags: vba, excel, hide

I have done research and for whatever reason I cannot get this simple code to work correctly.  Simply put, I am trying to `xlveryhidden` 5 tabs, but I receive `run-time error 1004`.  If anything, it would be nice to change from the Sheet names to code names in case I change the tab names:

- Sheet1 - Calculations
- Sheet2 - LY Rates
- Sheet3 - TY Rates
- Sheet4 - Client Details
- Sheet5 - Census

---

```
Sub VeryHiddenTabs()
    Sheets(Array("Calculations", "LY Rates", "TY Rates", "Client Details", "Census")).Visible = xlVeryHidden
End Sub
```

Comment: Try this https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/732891-excel-2010-excel-vba-hide-sheets-using-code-names-not-sheet-names.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use this to set my sheets to `.Visible = False`.

```
Sub HideMySheets()
    Sheets(Array(Sheet1.Name, Sheet2.Name, Sheet3.Name, Sheet4.Name, Sheet5.Name)).Visible = False
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, it turns out you are not allowed to use this method to set them to `.Visible = xlVeryHidden`. Instead you have to do it on a per-sheet basis, using @Ibo's method.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have provided it seems you are trying to make all of the sheets very hidden, you cannot do this. You MUST have at least one VISIBLE sheet in the workbook.

Additionally, to use VBA to make sheets very hidden not using the sheet names, you should then use the sheet indexes or sheets' code name. Sheets code name cannot be change using the interface so the code would work with whatever the sheet name is. To change the sheets' code name, go to VBE (ALT + F11), double click on the sheet you want and change the name, which is the first item in the properties window, if you don't see the properties window click F4. Let's say you change the code name of the sheet to `mySht1` then you can do:

```
mySht1.Visible = xlVeryHidden
```

if you use the index of the sheets to change the visibility you can do this:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).visible=xlVeryHidden
```

if you want to use this method, you need to always have one visible sheet so you have to create a sheet and then run this code:

```
Sub VeryHiddenTabs()
    For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count - 1
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Visible = xlVeryHidden
    Next
End Sub
```

since you have already had the sheet you have mentioned, then Excel will make all of the very hidden. The above routine will keep the last created sheet visible and the rest very hidden.